# Paginating all collections on entity-relationships in JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, eclipselink

I have an entity that looks like the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FooTable")
public class FooEntity {
    private Collection<BarEntity> bar;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fooField")
    public Collection<BarEntity> getBars() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBars(Collection<BarEntity> barByFooId) {
        this.bar = barByFooId;
    }
}
```

Basically a one-to-many relationship.

What I want, is that when I have an instance of `FooEntity`, I want to be able to return the assosciated `Collection<BarEntity>` in a paginated way using Spring Page.

I've set it up in this way in my repository:

```
@Override
@Query("select child from FooEntity p inner join p.barField child where p = :parent")
public Page<BarEntity> findBy(FooEntity parent, Pageable pageable)
```

Which works. For the one relationship.

However! Many of my entity models have a one-to-many relationship to the so-called `BarEntity`. What I need is a way to tell spring to **Always** paginate my related entities, because I'd rather not write a specific implementation for each entity that has this type of relation.

Is there any way I can specify this behaviour with *minimal* code repetition?

Comment: No. But please tell me how you would like this implementation look like?

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're asking. Implementation of which part?

Comment: How would you like Spring Data to do the job you are asking for.

Comment: Well, I'd like any point where we say `foo.getBars()` for that to return `Page<BarEntity>`. This is existing functionality. I'd just like to specify that functionality on every entity that has a one-to-many connection with Bars, not just on the FooEntity.

So it's not so much of a question of "How would Spring do this?" but more a question of "How do we tell spring what we want it to do _once_"

Comment: I think the implication is that this is a new feature, and you should file it as such. Such a feature would need to work out what it means to the model object itself - when you access foo.getBars() it fetches and stores everything in foo. When using paginated access, what does it mean if getBars already holds the completed list, and should it store/cache the partial list in there somehow? This is why you may need to define Spring methods for your specific requests, or create your own generic template for it.